# AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor appendPixelBuffer

Tags: iphone, ios

I used the code below to write image to video

```
-(void) writeImagesToMovieAtPath:(NSString *) path withSize:(CGSize) size
{
    NSLog(@"Write Started");

    NSError *error = nil;

    AVAssetWriter *videoWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:
                                  [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] fileType:AVFileTypeMPEG4
                                                              error:&error];
    NSParameterAssert(videoWriter);

    NSDictionary *videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                                   [NSNumber numberWithInt:size.width], AVVideoWidthKey,
                                   [NSNumber numberWithInt:size.height], AVVideoHeightKey,
                                   nil];

    AVAssetWriterInput* videoWriterInput = [[AVAssetWriterInput
                                             assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                             outputSettings:videoSettings] retain];


    AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor *adaptor = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor
                                                     assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:videoWriterInput
                                                     sourcePixelBufferAttributes:nil];

    NSParameterAssert(videoWriterInput);
    NSParameterAssert([videoWriter canAddInput:videoWriterInput]);
    videoWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;
    [videoWriter addInput:videoWriterInput];

    //Start a session:
    [videoWriter startWriting];
    [videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];

    CVPixelBufferRef buffer = NULL;

    //convert uiimage to CGImage.

    int frameCount = 16;
    int kRecordingFPS = 30;
    UIImage * im = [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_0103.JPG"];

    NSArray * imageArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:im,im,im,im,im,im,im,im,im,im,im,im,im,im,im,im, nil];

    for(UIImage * img in imageArray)
    {
        buffer = [self pixelBufferFromCGImage:[img CGImage] andSize:size];

        BOOL append_ok = NO;
        int j = 0;
        while (!append_ok && j < 30)
        {
            if (adaptor.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData)
            {
                printf("appending %d attemp %d\n", frameCount, j);

                CMTime frameTime = CMTimeMake(frameCount,(int32_t) kRecordingFPS);
                append_ok = [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:frameTime];

                if(buffer)
                    CVBufferRelease(buffer);
                [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.05];
            }
            else
            {
                printf("adaptor not ready %d, %d\n", frameCount, j);
                [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];
            }
            j++;
        }
        if (!append_ok) {
            printf("error appending image %d times %d\n", frameCount, j);
        }
        frameCount++;
    }


    //Finish the session:
    [videoWriterInput markAsFinished];
    [videoWriter finishWriting];
    NSLog(@"Write Ended");
    [videoWriterInput release];
    [videoWriter release];
    [imageArray release];
}
```

it works at first time, but if I run code 2,3 times or more,
it reported:

```
！appending 0 0-0 attemp 0
！appending 0 0-0 attemp 1
My App(11385,0xb0103000) malloc: *** error for object 0x9ab4270: double free
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
！appending 0 0-0 attemp 2
My App(11385,0xb0103000) malloc: *** error for object 0x9ab4270: double free
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
！appending 0 0-0 attemp 3
```

Soemtime it caused crashing

I try to find the reason but no result,

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of using [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];
use
**while(!adaptor.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData)
{}**

Because many times **readyForMoreMediaData** never sets to YES in 0.1 time interval.

Also try to free memory occupied by **appendPixelBuffer:withPresentationTime:** method
actually this method stops you from successful run

Comment: this causes memory warning and exit app on device

Comment: if(buffer)
                    CVBufferRelease(buffer); to free mem

Comment: You can manage it in the  appendPixelBuffer:withPresentationTime:  method only. Because at each loop this method creates context, buffer and all take so much memory on device. approx it takes more than 1MB per loop.

Comment: I am having this same problem but don't understand your comment about "You can manage it in the appendPixelBuffer:withPresentationTime: method only". How do i free the memory *inside* that method? As far as I know, appendPixelBuffer:withPresentationTime: is a AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor class's method and cannot be changed.

Comment: @Vlad, did you figure out how to avoid memory overflow?

Answer (score 1):

You need  to release your buffer with CFRelease(), as it is described in [The Create Rule](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-CJBEJBHH)

```
if ([assetWriterInput isReadyForMoreMediaData]) {
    CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = [self newPixelBufferFromCGImage:image.CGImage];
    CMTime frameTime = CMTimeMake(frameCount,(int32_t) kRecordingFPS);
    if (![adaptor appendPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer withPresentationTime:frameTime]) {
        NSError *error = [videoWriter error];
        NSLog(@"failed to append sbuf: %@", error);
    }
    CFRelease(pixelBuffer);
}
```

Comment: This answer is correct but unsafe. CFRelease is not NULL safe, so if the pixel buffer is not actually created this code will crash your application. You should instead use CVPixelBufferRelease which is NULL safe