# Memory leak after call CGContextDrawImage

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, uiimage

I've read all CGContextDrawImage memory peak answers, I tried but none of the solutions work yet.

Here is my code, after call CGContextDrawImage, memory increase 10-40MB. I'm using this code to generate a video from images, if I have 200 images, the app crash.

Loop through images:

```
for(UIImage * img in imageArray)
{

    buffer = [self pixelBufferFromCGImage:[img CGImage] ImageSize:img.size];

    BOOL append_ok = NO;
    int j = 0;
    while (!append_ok) {
        if (adaptor.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData)  {
            //print out status:
            NSLog(@"Processing video frame (%d,%lu)",frameCount,(unsigned long)[imageArray count]);

            CMTime frameTime = CMTimeMake(frameCount*frameDuration,(int32_t) fps);
            append_ok = [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:frameTime];
            if(!append_ok){
                NSError *error = videoWriter.error;
                if(error!=nil) {
                    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@,%@.", error, [error userInfo]);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            printf("adaptor not ready %d, %d\n", frameCount, j);
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];
        }
    }
    if (!append_ok) {
        printf("error appending image %d times %d\n, with error.", frameCount, j);
    }
    frameCount++;
}
```

Here is pixelBufferFromCGImage function

```
- (CVPixelBufferRef) pixelBufferFromCGImage: (CGImageRef) image ImageSize:(CGSize)size {

NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey,
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey,
                         nil];
CVPixelBufferRef pxbuffer = NULL;

CVReturn status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                      size.width,
                                      size.height,
                                      kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB,
                                      (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) options,
                                      &pxbuffer);
if (status != kCVReturnSuccess){
    NSLog(@"Failed to create pixel buffer");
}

CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);
void *pxdata = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pxbuffer);

CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pxdata, size.width,
                                             size.height, 8, 4*size.width, rgbColorSpace,
                                             kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
//kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);
CGContextConcatCTM(context, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0));
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, CGImageGetWidth(image),
                                       CGImageGetHeight(image)), image);
CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorSpace);
CGContextRelease(context);
CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);
return pxbuffer;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor appendPixelBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523535/avassetwriterinputpixelbufferadaptor-appendpixelbuffer)

Comment: See the linked question - your code looks like copy & paste with the same issue - you're creating  `CVPixelBuffer`, but not releasing it anywhere -> `CFRelease(buffer)` in your loop (check for `!= NULL`).

Comment: yes, kind of that. The correct answer is CVPixelBufferRelease(buffer); to release the buffer

Comment: Just FYI - `CVPixelBufferRelease` is equivalent to `CFRelease`. The only difference is that `CVPixelBufferRelease` is `NULL` safe.